# What is have been /has been grammar rules?

Tags: grammar, structure

Do I have to include verb+ing after have been/has been? Can I use verb+ed after have been/has been? Please explain with example.

Answer (score 2):

The following are grammatical constructions:

1. They have been cooking.
2. They have been cooked.
3. He has been cooking.
4. He has been cooked.

You should know, however, that the first and third constructions are active-voice constructions, so "they" and "he," are the ones doing the cooking.  The second and fourth constructions are passive-voice constructions, so "they" and "he" themselves are cooked, not the doing the cooking.

Answer (score 0):

Per my reading of the question, "have" normally refers to a plural while "has" is singular both referencing the proceeding object be it an event or noun. Verb+ing is generally used for the plural verb+ed for the singular as in. "strange things have been happening" "a strange thing has happened".